# Json to table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert below data into a SQL Server table

```
{ 
    "ITEM_NUMBER":"CSC-ENVM",
    "SHIPPED_DATE":"1995-08-22T00:00:00",
    "STATUS":"Shipped",
    "SOURCE":"Shipment"
},
{ 
    "ITEM_NUMBER":"NP-2R",
    "SHIPPED_DATE":"1995-03-14T18:23:00",
    "STATUS":"Shipped",
    "SOURCE":"Shipment"
}
```

### **ITEM_NUMBER| SHIPPED_DATE      | STATUS   | SOURCE

### CSC-ENVM   |1995-08-22T00:00:00| Shipped  | Shipment

NP-2R      |1995-03-14T18:23:00|Shipped   |Shipment**

Comment: SQL Server **2008** has no direct, built-in support for JSON. You need to use some other tool - a language like C#, Ruby, PHP or whatever you're comfortable with - to read this JSON, convert it to objects, and then insert those objects and their values into SQL Server

Comment: Just use a regular `INSERT` statement, targeting a varchar/nvarchar column of the needed maximum length.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert into table of a column with Varchar column as mentioned in comments as well

```
insert into #temp
select '{ 
    "ITEM_NUMBER":"CSC-ENVM",
    "SHIPPED_DATE":"1995-08-22T00:00:00",
    "STATUS":"Shipped",
    "SOURCE":"Shipment"
},
{ 
    "ITEM_NUMBER":"NP-2R",
    "SHIPPED_DATE":"1995-03-14T18:23:00",
    "STATUS":"Shipped",
    "SOURCE":"Shipment"
}'
```

In SQL 2008,you also can read this JSON data using ParseJson function created by Phil Factor.you can read on about that here...

[Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)